# Java EE (Spring) Multithreading to divide work

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a simple scenario where in response to a user action:

`JSP ===> Controller ===> Service ===> DAO`

DAO essentially running a number of disparate queries. Is there a way for the service to call multiple DAOs or DAO methods concurrently, have each perform its one complex query and the have the service aggregate the result from each DAO?

Can use JMS, but how to return the results back to the originating service? 
Same goes for spring-batch.

It appears these mechanisms are good to perform work which does not need to be 'returned' to a higher layer.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the @Async annotation combined with a returntype of Future.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

you will still need to wait and collect all the result before returning it to the higher layer.

if this is not good enough, you might wanna look at websockets push or longpolling in the web-tier, but that makes the application more complex